# Apache Commons Crypto Linking Error

Tags: java, apache, cryptography

When using the OpenSSL backed cipher as follows:

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.setProperty(CryptoCipherFactory.CLASSES_KEY,
 CipherProvider.OPENSSL.getClassName());
```

I get the following error:

```
java.security.GeneralSecurityException: CryptoCipher {org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSslCipher} is not available or transformation AES/CTR/NoPadding is not supported
```

:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup
        at org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSslNative.initIDs(Native Method)
        at org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSslCipher.<init>(OpenSslCipher.java:57)
```

This is caused by a linking failure to OpenSSl, as far as I can tell. My t LD_LIBRARY_PATH is configured to pointing to /usr/local/lib which contains libssl and libcrypto. What am I missing?

I run my code as

java -cp nameofjar.jar my.package.name

Comment: How does it follow.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry?

Comment: You said you use the cipher as follow, but din't write any code. That of course until you edit

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running with OpenSSL 3 where ACT supports 1.0.x, 1.1.x, and 2.x.